# Hiding Content from Mobile (SEO)

Tags: css, seo, media-queries

Do you think the hiding particular content from the mobile version of a website can harm your SEO? I have a page that has around 3 long paragraphs of content. On the desktop, this looks fine - but on a mobile there is far too much content before being able to click my categories on the page. What I've decided to do is write a media query to hide all but the first paragraph in this section. Could Google think that I'm trying to use black-hat techniques or would they understand that my content is visible on mobile?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO and not directly about programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

The `{display:none}` tag within your CSS for the para you're trying to hide will be read by Google. But the question here lies whether they will consider it after parsing the media query.

Highly doubtful considering they read "present" code and do not read multiple instances of it, as recorded spider data is mainly the code on your HTML page without considering the ifs and buts of CSS & JS.

IMO, you should not be penalised for this as long as your content is unique and you're not indulging in any black-hat tactics.

Comment: I've hidden the content using: `@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) { .hide { display:none; } }` - making the long text visible on most tablets, desktop browsers and some large (or landscape orientated) mobile devices. I'll keep an eye on it and see how it performs.

Comment: It will perform as expected as Google spiders only read the content within the parent HTML and index using that content. In other words, Google will see a web page like the Lynx browser does.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this one for hiding content for mobile devices.

```css
@media all and (max-width: 479px) {

.content .mobilehide{
  
  display: none;
  
  }
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  
  <p class="mobilehide"> This will hide on mobile version </p>
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's hard for most of us to know at what point Google will draw the line and say that your site is breaking cloaking rules.

Maybe take a look at [this forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/gKzCkuZva2o) on Google's Product Forum for a little more info.